# Select option hide and show when counter changes

Tags: javascript, html, select, element

I have some dropdown menu where I want to hide value 550282, if amount of guests is greater to 2 and show when amount of guest is less or equal to 2.

Guest Count is added by JavaScript functions below.

Is this possible through jQuery or there is another method? Snipped code is there and also the `[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3cbntb3/14/).`

```js
var hostAmount = 1;
var hosts = [1];

function getSelect(index) {
  var retHTML = '<span class="label">Host ' + (index + 1) + ': </span><select name="host' + (index + 1) + '" id="host' + (index + 1) + '">';
  if (hosts[index] == 1)
    retHTML += '<option value="1" selected="selected">Dospělý</option><option value="2" >Dítě do 15</option><option value="3">Dítě do 10</option><option value="4">Přistýlka</option><option value="5">Vlastní postýlka</option></select>';
  else
    retHTML += '<option value="1">Dospělý (130Kč)</option><option value="2" selected="selected">Dítě do 15(130Kč)</option><option value="3">Dítě do 10(1Kč)</option><option value="4">Přistýlka</option><option value="5">Vlastní postýlka</option></select>';
  if (index != 0)
    retHTML += '<span class="delete" onclick="deleteHost(' + index + ');">Smazat</span><br />';
  else
    retHTML += '<br />';
  return retHTML;
}

function saveValues() {
  for (var i = 1; i < hostAmount; i++)
    hosts[i] = document.getElementById("host" + (i + 1)).value;
}

function actualSelects() {
  var HTMLbuff = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < hosts.length; i++)
    HTMLbuff += getSelect(i);
  document.getElementById("personBox").innerHTML = HTMLbuff;
  document.getElementById("amount").value = hostAmount;
}

function addHost() {
  saveValues();
  hosts.push(1);
  hostAmount++;
  actualSelects();
}

function deleteHost(index) {
  hosts.splice(index, 1);
  hostAmount--;
  actualSelects();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body onload="actualSelects()">
    <form>
        <span class="label">Guest Count: </span><input readonly name="amount" id="amount" type="number" value="1" min="1" /><br />
        <div id="personBox">
        </div>
        <span id="addPerson" onclick="addHost();">Add Host</span><br />

        <span>Option</span>
        <select name="room-type" class="dropdown-list">
      <option id="toremove" selected="selected" value="550282">550282</option>
      <option value="550280">550280</option>
      <option  value="557786">557786</option>
      <option value="550284">557786</option>
    </select>
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can hide the selection by `document.getElementById("toremove").style.display="none";`,
then show it up by `document.getElementById("toremove").style.display="";` when guest count <=2.

```js
var hostAmount = 1;
var hosts = [1];

function getSelect(index) {
  var retHTML = '<span class="label">Host ' + (index + 1) + ': </span><select name="host' + (index + 1) + '" id="host' + (index + 1) + '">';
  if (hosts[index] == 1)
    retHTML += '<option value="1" selected="selected">Dospělý</option><option value="2" >Dítě do 15</option><option value="3">Dítě do 10</option><option value="4">Přistýlka</option><option value="5">Vlastní postýlka</option></select>';
  else
    retHTML += '<option value="1">Dospělý (130Kč)</option><option value="2" selected="selected">Dítě do 15(130Kč)</option><option value="3">Dítě do 10(1Kč)</option><option value="4">Přistýlka</option><option value="5">Vlastní postýlka</option></select>';
  if (index != 0)
    retHTML += '<span class="delete" onclick="deleteHost(' + index + ');">Smazat</span><br />';
  else
    retHTML += '<br />';
  return retHTML;
}

function saveValues() {
  for (var i = 1; i < hostAmount; i++)
    hosts[i] = document.getElementById("host" + (i + 1)).value;
}

function actualSelects() {
  var HTMLbuff = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < hosts.length; i++)
    HTMLbuff += getSelect(i);
  document.getElementById("personBox").innerHTML = HTMLbuff;
  document.getElementById("amount").value = hostAmount;
}

function addHost() {
  saveValues();
  hosts.push(1);
  hostAmount++;
  actualSelects();
  if(hostAmount>2) { 
    document.getElementById("toremove").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("toselect").value = ""; //reset the value of select
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("toremove").style.display="";
  }
}

function deleteHost(index) {
  hosts.splice(index, 1);
  hostAmount--;
  actualSelects();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body onload="actualSelects()">
    <form>
        <span class="label">Guest Count: </span><input readonly name="amount" id="amount" type="number" value="1" min="1" /><br />
        <div id="personBox">
        </div>
        <span id="addPerson" onclick="addHost();">Add Host</span><br />

        <span>Option</span>
        <select name="room-type" class="dropdown-list" id="toselect">
      <option id="toremove" selected="selected" value="550282">550282</option>
      <option value="550280">550280</option>
      <option value="557786">557786</option>
      <option value="550284">557786</option>
    </select>
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.  I'm an idiot, the solution was so simple and right in front of me.